# Understanding the definition of path connected subspace

Tags: general-topology, definition, path-connected

If $X $ is a topological space and $ Y $ is a subspace of $ X$, then what does it mean when we say  $Y$ is a path connected subspace of $X$?

Does it mean that any two points $ x $ and $ y $ in $ Y $ has a path in $Y$ (like if $X $ is path connected then any two points $ x $ and $y $ in $X$  has a path in $X$) ?

Comment: $(X, \tau) $  and $Y\subset X$  is path connected  iff $(Y, \tau_Y) $ path connected. $x, y\in Y $ , $\exists \text { a path } $ $\gamma :[0, 1]\to X $ such that $\gamma[0, 1]\subset Y$

Comment: Yes. Your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is path-connected if we consider in $Y$ the subspace topology. This is the same thing as asserting that, if $x,y\in Y$, the there is a continuous map $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow X$ such that $\gamma\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\subset Y$, that $\gamma(0)=x$ and that $\gamma(1)=y$.

Comment: Can I not then write directly the map from [0,1] to Y instead of writing separately that the image in subset of Y?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in order to determine whether or not $\gamma$ is continuous, you have to keep in mind that $Y$ is endowed with the subspace topology. And then continuity is the same thing as $\gamma$ being continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ into $X$.

Comment: @Esha continuity is a topological property. If $\gamma : [0, 1]\to Y $ be the path, then you have to prove continuity w.r.to the subspace topology $\tau_Y$

Comment: @Jose how do you say that for codomain being Y, the continuity w.r.t. the subspace topology on Y is same as the continuity w.r.t. the topology on X?

Comment: That's a property of the subspace topology. Do you want a proof?

Comment: @Jose A proof will be helpful.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ into $Y$, and if $A$ is an open subset of $X$, then, since the $\gamma([0,1])\subset Y$, $\gamma^{-1}(A)=\gamma^{-1}(A\cap Y)$, which is an open subset of $[0,1]$, since $A\cap Y$ is an open subset of $Y$. So, $\gamma$ is continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ into $X$. And if $\gamma$ is continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ into $X$ and if $A$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $A=B\cap Y$ for some open subset $B$ of $X$, and so $\gamma^{-1}(A)=\gamma^{-1}(B)$, which is an open subset of $[0,1]$. So, $\gamma$ is continuous as a map from $[0,1]$ into $Y$.